# Silex : Dynamic forms

Tags: forms, silex

Dear helpers and saviors !

I'm trying to create some dynamic forms with Silex.

My objective is to have the user create a state in a existing country. I would like him/her to select a region (like Asia, Europe, America...), then select a country to which link the newly created state.

I have some "classic" and simple forms extending AbstractType, in which the user can select the country directly. I created a choice list based on a call to a DAO (database) to find all available countries. I would like to add a region choice_list field to reduce the number of available country (and reduce the database charge as well even if it isn't my main goal).

I've seen http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data, but it seem that we can't create subform for elements that are "parents" of the main class (or that i did not understood how), saying that the link is not stored in my object i would like to create. What i would like to do here is to add a field for the 2-level above (state->country->region), not direcly linked  (a state have a country, and a country have a region) region.

I do not manage to imagine or code it properly, or even simply displaying.
Please note that i'll have to do it on several levels (state, city, and some other classes), and i would like to find a quite generic way to do it (understand not a ready solution for this particular example).

Any ideas ?
Please excuse my english, and thank you very much for your help !
For reference, here are my DB links between objects :

- Region : ID and Name
- Country : Codes, ID, Name and link to Region's ID
- State : Codes, ID, Name and link to Country's ID
- City : Name, ID and link to State's ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do what i wanted.

I created supplementary forms, asking for filling each of the "parent" objects.

So in addition to my Types forms, i now have a selection a Select forms, allowing me to select Region, then Country, then State.